# Correcta estructura de un proyecto en django

Tags: django

Desde hace unos meses estoy trabajando con `Django` y hay una serie de dudas que no consigo responder a pesar de leer y ver vídeos.

Hasta la fecha yo tengo un código que aparentemente funciona bien, pero si yo leo la documentación, está claro que o hay cosas incorrectas o al menos hay cosas que no aprovechan el 100% del potencial de `Django`.

Mi web básicamente se divide en 3 secciones, una de ella muestra una serie de tablas con valores, otra muestra gráficos y otra imágenes y un mapa. Por lo tanto, para esto aprendí que lo que debía hacer es un `index.html` al cual le defino una barra de navegación y un footer que serán común a todas las secciones y mediante `{% block content %}{% endblock%}` llamó a las diferentes secciones.

Pero a todo esto hay que retroceder, el primer paso a la hora de crear el proyecto es hacer

```
django-admin startproject mysite
```

Esto bien, no hay problema. Segundo, `migrate` para las bases de datos

```
python manage.py migrate
```

Este paso por ahora lo obviaré, pues por ahora no me interesan las bases de datos (en un futuro cercano si).

Perfecto, yo aquí ya puedo empezar a desarrollar mi proyecto y efectivamente eso es lo que hice, cree una carpeta para mis `templates`, otra para mis `css`,`js`, etc.

Llegados a este punto veo que hay una cosa que no he hecho, crear una app, ¿exactamente cuando son útiles? ¿Yo debía haber creado una para cada sección? ¿Una que englobe las tres (pues aunque sean 3 son los mismos datos desde diferentes perspectivas)?

En mi caso, lo que yo hice fue en el fichero `views.py`

```
# FUNCIONES QUE REPRESENTAN A LAS PÁGINAS PRINCIPALES
# Para simplificar el ejemplo pongo ctx = {'Vacio':0} pero aquí llamo a
# funciones que inicializan la pág.

def img_mapa(request):
    ctx = {'Vacio':0}
    return render(request,'img_map.html', ctx)

def graficos_analisis(request):
    ctx = {'Vacio':0}
    return render(request,'graficos.html', ctx)

def data(request):
    ctx = {'Table':0} #nada
    return render(request, 'data.html', ctx)
```

Y a partir de aquí fui creando diferentes funciones que van realizando las tareas pertinentes. Entonces la primera pregunta, ¿las apps eran necesarias aquí? ¿Cuando son útiles?¿Las apps y los modelos son lo mismo? Porque yo no los uso.

Mi estructura ahora es:

```
miProyecto
  > carpetaScriptsPython
  > static
    > cssFiles
    > jsFiles
  > templates
  __init__.py
  settings.py
  urls.py
  views.py
  wsgi.py
  db.sqlite3
  manage.py
```

Muchas gracias

Comment: Todas tus dudas tienen respuesta en la documentación de Django: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/applications/#projects-and-applications

Comment: Con la documentación de django he llegado a todo eso que hice, pero no consigo aclarar las dudas que pongo aquí, imagino es sencillo pero me está costando dar este paso para que todo mi proyecto sea más profesional.